# Get a list of ids as a result of a mongoengine query

Tags: django, mongodb, django-queryset, mongoengine, scalar

I am executing a query with mongoengine. As a result I want to get a list of ids to continue working with them.

When I use `.scalar("id")` I get a queryset with objects ids

```
  Test.objects.filter(is_deleted=False).scalar("id")    --> [ObjectId(kasdfji93jiasdkfj),....]
```

For my following raw query i need this Format [kasdfji93jiasdkfj,....]

```
 { field: { $in: [kasdfji93jiasdkfj,....] } }
```

Does anybody know an approch without iterating through the queryset to build this list?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the ObjectId's to strings and that means iterating the queryset.

Why do you need them to be strings in the $in query - its more efficient to store ObjectIds.